# how to create an image uploader

Tags: php, image, uploader

So I am trying to create an image upload for my website but I want each user to be able to upload there own picture. I have a working code but I cant figure out how to set it to where each user can upload there own picture. I know it has to do with the session start but I don't know what. I am self teaching myself code so I am still clueless about a lot.

```
<?php session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = "buttcakes";
 ?>
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']  
   ['tmp_name'],"picture/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $con = mysqli_connect (all correct on my end);
            $q = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE user3 SET image = '".$_FILES    
   ['file']['name']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="file">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit">
            </form>
             <?php
                    $con = mysqli_connect
     ("local", "mine", "", "mine");
                    $q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user3");
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
                            echo $row['username'];
                            if($row['image'] == ""){
                                    echo "<img width='100' height='100'  
    src='picture/default.jpg' alt='Default Profile Pic'>";
                            } else {
                                    echo "<img width='100' height='100'    
    src='picture/".$row['image']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";
                            }
                            echo "<br>";
                    }
            ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM user3 WHERE username = 'YOUR USER NAME'`

Comment: @u_mulder where do I put this code at